# How to show tab with carousel avoiding sliding from the current image to the selected image?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, carousel

In my Angular app I have a simple twitter-bootstrap carousel, in a tab:

```
<div class="tabbable">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li ng-class="{active: tabSelected === 'main'}">
      <a href="" ng-click="tabSelected = 'main'">Main</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-class="{active: tabSelected === 'photos'}">
      <a href="" ng-click="tabSelected = 'photos'">Photos</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

...

<div class="tab-content" ng-show="tabSelected === 'photos'>
  <div class="slides-control">
    <carousel disable-animation="false">
      <slide ng-repeat="photo in person.photos" active="photo.active">
        <img class="slide" ng-src="{{photo.path}}" />
      </slide>
    </carousel>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the controller I have defined a method, `tabSelect(tabName, photoNumber)`, which allows the tab to be selected in code, and - if the tab is the one named 'photos' - a specific image number can be selected:

```
<script>
  $scope.tabSelect = function (tabName, photoNumber) {
    if (tabName === 'photos') {
      $scope.person.photos[0].active = false;
      $scope.person.photos[photoNumber].active = true;
    }
    $scope.tabSelected = tabName;
  };
</script>
```

The problem is this:

*When calling, for example, `$scope.tabSelect('photos', 7);`, the photos tab is shown, but initially the previously active image is shown, and then immediately it slides to the selected image (the 7th, in the example). I don't want to avoid using animations, which are quite cool... Though, I want to display immediately the selected image...

I did already try to surround the `$scope.tabSelected = tabName;` instruction in a $timeout() block, and the selected slide is immediately shown, but not fully rendered (for example, the arrows are not present...).*